# Enforcing type in "generic" code with empty interfaces

Tags: go

Sorry for the ambiguous title.

I'm reading this book http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/ and I thought it would be good to implement the examples in Go as a learning exercise, however the book uses Java as its language to describe code in.

One of the first chapters discusses setting up some core datatypes/container style classes to re-use later on but I'm having trouble trying to hammer these into a Go setting, mainly because these datatypes seem to be enjoying the use of Java generics.

For example, I've written the following code

```
package bag

type T interface{}
type Bag []T

func (a *Bag) Add(t T) {
    *a = append(*a, t)
}

func (a *Bag) IsEmpty() bool {
    return len(*a) == 0
}

func (a *Bag) Size() int {
    return len(*a)
}
```

This works in principle in the sense that I can add items to a `Bag` and check its size and everything. However this also means that the following code is legal

```
a := make(bag.Bag,0,0)
a.Add(1)
a.Add("Hello world!")
a.Add(5.6)
a.Add(time.Now())
```

I was just wondering if there was any way of enforcing the type so it conforms to a contract similar to

```
Bag<T> bagOfMyType = new Bag<T>()
```

e.g.

```
Bag<Integer> bagOfInts = new Bag<Integer>()
```

I know Go doesn't have generics and they're not really The Go Way, but I was just wondering if it is a possible to "enforce" anything at compile time (probably not)

Sorry for the long post

**EDIT:** OK so I've been looking into this a little further, I've pretty much given up with the generics side of things (I understand this is not on the roadmap for Go) so I'm thinking of doing something similar to Haskell typeclasses with interfaces, e.g.

```
type T interface{}
type Bag interface {
    Add(t T)
    IsEmpty() bool
    Size() int
}

type IntSlice []int

func (i *IntSlice) Add(t T) {
    *i = append(*i, t.(int)) // will throw runtime exception if user attempts to add anything other than int
}

func (i *IntSlice) IsEmpty() bool {
    return len(*i) == 0
}

func (i *IntSlice) Size() int {
    return len(*i)
}
```

The problem with this is the type enforcement is only enforced at runtime.

Anyone got any ideas how to improve on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm new to Go myself, so I'm curious if someone will have a better answer, but here's how I see it:

You want compile-time enforcement that when `Add()` is called on an `IntSlice`, its parameter is an `int`.  Well, here's how you do that:

```
func (i *IntSlice) Add(t int) {
    *i = append(*i, t)
}
```

Since there aren't generics, the `Add()` method is going to be different for every type of `Bag`, so the `Bag` interface, assuming you need it, becomes just:

```
type Bag interface {
    IsEmpty() bool
    Size() int
}
```

That makes sense to me, because you can't pass a `Bag` around and throw just anything in it.  Knowing that something is a `Bag` isn't enough to know how to call `Add()` on it; you must know what type of `Bag` you're dealing with.

You could make the interface specific to the type, like `IntBag`, but since only one type is actually going to satisfy that interface, you might as well get rid of the interface and change the name of `IntSlice` to `IntBag`.

Basically that means giving up entirely on anything generic-like, and just creating a type with some methods that do what you want:

```
type IntBag []int

func (b *IntBag) Add(i int) {
    *b = append(*b, i)
}

func (b IntBag) IsEmpty() bool {
    return len(b) == 0
}

func (b IntBag) Size() int {
    return len(b)
}
```

**Update:** Sometimes generics really would come in handy.  It seems to me we're left choosing on a case-by-case basis what exactly is best for a given problem.  With empty interfaces and reflection, you can get some generic-like behavior, but it tends to be ugly and you give up some compile-time type checking.  Or you give up on generics and have some code-duplication. Or you just do it a totally different way.

I asked a question a few weeks ago about how I should use Go to handle problems that look to me like they need class hierarchies. The answer was basically that there is no general solution; it's all case-by-case. I think the same applies for generics: there are no generics in Go, and there's no general solution for translating generics-based solutions to Go.

There are many cases where you might use generics in another language but interfaces are perfectly adequate (or truly shine) in Go.  Your example here is one where interfaces aren't really a proper replacement.  See also: [Go Vs. Generics](http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/GoVsGenerics).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The only problem I can see with this is if you want to use the ```Add``` method in any function that takes a ```Bag``` interface as a parameter (it won't work) but I suppose that's the trade off you'll have to make with this solution....

Comment: So if you wanted to make it non-generic you would need to create one function for dealing with ```IntBag```, another function for dealing with ```StringBag``` and so on, unless you created some sort of "dispatcher" entry point that reflects on the ```Bag``` and distributes the call according to the type. That still means writing ```n``` functions though

Comment: @djhworld I added an update at the bottom of my answer in response to your comments.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, I think I might have to give up on my quest to do the algorithms book exercises in Go, but oh well. thanks anyway man

Comment: @djhworld I'm sure you'd still be able to work through the book in Go if you were determined to, but indeed it might be simpler to use Java in order to focus on learning the material rather than dealing with language differences.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty well-versed with Go. Generics are a hotly-debated topic, and there is currently nothing analogous to Java generics or C++ templates. The convention at the moment is to implement a "generic" type with an empty interface and then wrap it with a specific type implementation that makes sure only elements of that type are used. Here's an example with `container/list` from the Go standard library.

http://play.golang.org/p/9w9H1EPHKR

```
package main

import (
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
)

type IntList struct {
    innerList *list.List
}

func NewIntList() *IntList {
    return &IntList{list.New()}
}

func (l *IntList) Add(i int) {
    // this is the only way to add an element to the list,
    // and the Add() method only takes ints, so only ints
    // can be added
    l.innerList.PushBack(i)
}

func (l *IntList) Last() int {
    lastElem := l.innerList.Back()

    // We can safely type-assert to an int, because Add()
    // guarantees that we can't put a non-int into our list
    return lastElem.Value.(int)
}

func main() {
    l := NewIntList()
    l.Add(5)
    l.Add(4)
    l.Add(3)
    l.Add(2)
    l.Add(1)
    fmt.Println("Expecting 1; got:", l.Last())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go now supports generics (from version 1.18 onwards): https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/generics

Here's an illustration based the example in the question:

```golang
import "time"

type Bag[T any] []T

func (a *Bag[T]) Add(t T) {
    *a = append(*a, t)
}

func (a *Bag[T]) IsEmpty() bool {
    return len(*a) == 0
}

func (a *Bag[T]) Size() int {
    return len(*a)
}

func main() {
    indiscriminateBag := make(Bag[any], 0, 0)
    indiscriminateBag.Add(1)
    indiscriminateBag.Add("Hello world!")
    indiscriminateBag.Add(5.6)
    indiscriminateBag.Add(time.Now())

    selectiveBag := make(Bag[int], 0, 0)
    selectiveBag.Add(1)
    selectiveBag.Add(1.25) // Compiler complains: cannot use 1.25 (untyped float constant) as int value in argument to selectiveBag.Add
}
```

I'm adding this answer here just in case anyone else new to Go stumbles across this question.

Incidentally, I also started thinking about Go generics while implementing the Princeton algorithms course in Go. Here are some [generic symbol tables](https://github.com/simoncrowe/algo/tree/main/internal/symbol_table)